# Updated MAMP and localhost on MacOS site no longer accessible

Tags: wp-admin

I have tried to access my site on localhost:8888/ and it no longer loads with any formatting since updating MAMP to a newer version.  I am able to access the db through phpMyAdmin but not sure what is what. There is no back-up either since it was on a local machine (my bad!).  This whole issue arose when someone asked if "I could view the site somewhere other than your computer at my leisure".  After a few google searches and trying quite a few solutions, which did not work, I've lost my ability to log-into this site and make any changes or even view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upgrade MAMP, it will preserve the existing installation to a folder that is called MAMP_current-date, something like MAMP_2022-04-14_08-00-00 (the last bit is a time stamp). You can revert to the previous version by renaming the current MAMP folder (under the Applications folder) or delete it, then rename the previous version with the date and time stamp appended to just MAMP. Then restart the MAMP services to see if you can access your WP site.

Comment: Genius!!  I cannot thank you enough.  At first the page loaded but all the formatting was not available until I logged into my wp-admin.  Success.  After a week of freaking out, you singlehandedly gave me the answer to my solution.